# ul menu stopping .fadeOut() function

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate, html-lists

i making a ul menu to wordpress. I have menu items as list items and in some cases submenus. I have `display:none;` for submenus, but if you hover parent, it will slidedown.
after you move away with cursor, it fades out submenu in 2 seconds. Currently it works just as i described. when i hover, it slides down, when i move cursor away, it fades out, BUT, when i move cursor back durning the fadeout, it still fades out.
My question is: How i can stop the fadeout function, when i move cursor back to submenu.

Current code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#access li').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which will stop any current animation and by passing `true, true` as arguments, it will clear any queue of animations and jump to the end.

```
jQuery('#access li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)